# php insert statement has correct arguments but insert is returning false

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Ok so my insert should be fine but is returning false, $quote holds value i have checked. and my database is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m15gD.png) Hope another pair of eyes can spot this. I have been using the same insert style for the other php files, works fine. But this one is tricky...issit because of the foreign keys?

```
    <?php

$quote = $_POST["quote"];
require "init.php";

$query = "INSERT INTO `quote`(`quote_description`) VALUES('".$quote."');";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


//"INSERT INTO `quote`(`quote_description`) VALUES ('".$quote."');";

if($result)
{
    $response = array();
    $code = "submit_true";
    $message = "Quote success, Click Ok to continue";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));


}

else{
    $response = array();
    $code = "submit_false";
    $message = "Sorry, some server error occurred, please try again";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));


}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I am getting the following error after checking for errors:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (mydb.quote, CONSTRAINT fk_quote_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code; you're not doing that. Plus, there are a few unknowns here; if the POST array contains a value and the MySQL API used to connect with.

Comment: if `$quote` contains for example a quote `'` you will be sql injecting yourself. You should use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: `$con` is undefined, isn´t it?

Comment: You did not insert any of the remaining columns (which do not appear be nullable based on your table structure).

Comment: If `$result` is false **process the `mysqli_error($con)`** And then you can ___find out what the probelm is without having to ask us___ Debugging **101** use the features provided to identify your mistakes

Comment: it's returning me the false message array i have built. ok will check out on prepared statement

Comment: ^ ... [*No.... you need to refer to comment #1...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117189/php-insert-statement-has-correct-arguments-but-insert-is-returning-false#comment61775494_37117189) to get the *real* error as to why it is failing you here. Using a prepared statement may work but it won't tell you why your original code failed and may still fail you.

Comment: Well as a number of the OTHER columns in that table are not allowed to be NULL, _if I am reading your picture correctly_, I would bet that your query ERROR is saying something like `oy dipstick, these columns cannot be NULL, please add some data to them`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Isn't that what Boss Hogg used to say to Sheriff Rosco P. Coltrane? *lol* or the Sheriff to Enos? or both?! hahaha!!

Comment: @Fred-ii- _Surley you are not suggesting I am old enough to remember The Dukes Of Hazzard!_ Errr _Or whatever it was called_

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Yepper!* and the Dodge Charger

Comment: @Fred-ii- Brum Brum, cannot remember the sisters name, but I remember a lot of other things about her

Comment: no guys, i am not receiving like columns cannot be null, i am just returning that $result is false, means that the insert statement didn't pull through. Ok what i did was change it into a prepared statement and it's returning a true but it's not inserting. that's weird.

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `quote`(`quote_description`) VALUES(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s" ,$quote);
$stmt->execute();

Comment: `$stmt->execute()` => `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$con->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // rest of code`

Comment: @BowieChang In your code change the `if($result)` to `if(!$result)` if I am not mistaken `$result` will contain a result set (if any) or false if it failed. So first check if it is false, if it isn't then process your data. Don't assume your query was successful from the get go

Comment: yup the issue is with the fk, what can i do from here?


there was an error....Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`quote`, CONSTRAINT `fk_quote_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Answer (score 0):

When using INSERT in MySQL, you have to include all columns and values to be inserted. Try this;

```
$query = "INSERT INTO quote(quote_id, quote_description, quote_points, user_id, Quote_of_day_id) VALUES(NULL, '".$quote."', '".$points."', '".$user_id."', '".$qod_id."');";
```

If you don't have all the values to be inserted at time for this query, just set them to nothing. To add values later use UPDATE:

```
$query = "UPDATE quote SET user_id = 8 WHERE quote_id = 6";
```

Though this is a solution for inserting, it is insecure and vulnerable to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Here is the better object-oriented solution that is more secure, and I suggest using it over any other insecure INSERTS:

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO quote(quote_id, quote_description, quote_points, user_id, Quote_of_day_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);');
$stmt->bind_param('isiii', $quote_id, $quote, $points, $user_id, $qod_id);

$stmt->execute();
```

Also it is a good idea to add this to handle your POST data:

```
if(!isset($_POST["quote"])) {
    echo "Data not received correctly";
    exit();
}
```

Hope these examples help you. Wish you the best.

Comment: i will study further into your examples, in fact this is really great help. thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks @BowieChang

Comment: managed to do it. thanks mate and the rest of you as well. sorry if i seemed a bit beginnerish, i am. New to coding as well as stack overflow. Hope to continue to work with you all! Cheers.